# Handling file with firebase serve

Tags: node.js, file, google-cloud-functions, multer, firebase-tools

I'm trying to capture a file from the request with firebase server, but for some reason I can't. I usually use the multer in my node projects to handle it. Below I have two prints of a request on a simple express server and another with firebase will do. Is there a specific configuration I'm not adopting?

```
...
const app = require('express')();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const multer = require('multer');
...

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(multer().any());

// UPLOAD GC: POST
app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.files);
    res.send('ok'); 
})

Result console log >
i  functions: Beginning execution of "app"
>  []
```

---

Result console log of a simple express server

```
Server running on port 3000!
[ { fieldname: 'avatar',
    originalname: 'file.png',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'image/png',
    buffer: <Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 02 00 00 00 02 00 08 06 00 00 00 f4 78 d4 fa 00 00 11 ca 7a 54 58 74 52 61 77 20 70 72 6f 66 69 ... >,
    size: 7858 } ]
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: Okay, I removed them, thank you.

Comment: The log is printing `req.files` just fine, the content of your file is inside `req.files[0].buffer`. What output do you expect exactly?

Comment: The log that is printing the buffer is from an express server that I did just to make sure. And that's what I expect in the cloud functions project. When I run the firebase command and it raises a server locally and I try to send a file, the log is empty. Notice the result in the first set of code. It's just an empty array. I imagine you need some special configuration in the cloud function project, maybe in the file firebase.json